# Color code to int (NumberFormatExeption)

Tags: java, colors, formatting, int

Hey i have a method to get colors and i want to make the color it returns an integer and it does not work!
It returns a Color.(java.awt.Color)
and i tried:
`new Integer("0x" + myColor.toString());` and
`Integer.parseInt("0x" + myColor.toString());`
Same result ...
The Exeption is a NumberFormatExeption
So my question is :
Is there any efficient way to make a color code a valid integer?

Comment: Please show your [mcve] code and your full stacktrace exception message. Also, what type of "color code" are you referring to?

Comment: ??? just call `getRGB()` ??? -- `myColor.getRGB()`. If this doesn't work there are many more related methods in the [Color API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) that you'll want to look at.

Comment: `myColor.toString()` doesn't return a color in hex format (like `ffaaff`). It returns something like `java.awt.Color[r=255,g=170,b=255]` (I'm using java 1.7) and this String causes the `NumberFormatException`. As @HovercraftFullOfEels said, just call `myColor.getRGB()`

Comment: In the future, please check the Java API before coming here as that will save you a lot of trouble. Also please check the how to ask a question section of the [help] to see how to ask more complete questions, ones that have enough information to be answerable from the start.